# Shortest distance with choosing only one coordinates from number of coordinates in same vertical line using python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have a `list` = `coordinates` in which I have coordinates of all those points lying in XY plane.

There are more than **1500** points given in `coordinates` list. I have to find minimum distance from left most point to right most point in XY plane such that if two or more points lies in same vertical line only one of them is chosen for the path and hence distance calculation.

example of `coordinates` list is :

```
coordinates = [(-6, 0), (-5.82, 1.72), (-5.17, -0.27), (-4.28, 0.0), (-2.9, -0.74), (-2.9, -0.2), (-1.55, 0.08), (-1.37, -0.43), (4.8, -1.64), (4.92, -0.25), (5.05, -1.45), (5.36, -0.02), (6, 0)]
```

So in this case point `(-2.9,-0.74)` will not be considered.

How to use **Dijksra's Algorithm** for such case or any other fit algorithm for shortest path but also removing such points in vertical lines which are not required.

I was using `itertools` to `permutate` and find all possible paths and then distance and then minimum of it but it is not fit for points more than **1000** and also it was not possible to ignore same vertical line coordinates as I mentioned. Please help in `python`

Comment: The shortest path is always a segment between these 2 points.

Comment: That is too easy.  There must be more to the problem, such a choosing one point at each x-coordinate.